# gcc error unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'

Tags: python, c, cygwin, uwsgi

I install Python inside Cygwin, and then I enter 'easy_install uwsgi'.

It shows error:

```
gcc: 错误：unrecognized command line option ‘-rdynamic’
*** error linking uWSGI ***
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: See also [Unrecognized command line option `-rdynamic` on GCC v4.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212393) which is also in the context of Cygwin.  Succinctly, the `-rdynamic` option is related to ELF format object files and libraries, and Windows doesn't use that format.