# unrecognized command line option ‘-rdynamic’ on GCC v4.9.2

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, uwsgi

I'm using GCC v4.9.2 under Cygwin on Windows 7 64-bit, but running into an issue trying to compile [uWSGI](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi).

The error I'm receiving is -

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rdynamic’
```

GCC version output -

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.x86_64/src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.x86_64/src/gcc-4.9.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

I'm invoking the build with `CFLAGS="-Wno-error" make`.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I can see in the documentation from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-rdynamic-1090) that flag `-rdynamic` exists.

What am I missing?

Comment: See also [GCC error 'unrecognized command line option `-rdynamic`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230082), which is also attempting to install uWSGI on Window with Cygwin.  However, it doesn't have an answer at all (just a comment I've added x-ref'ing this question), so this question can't really be made a duplicate of that one, but the opposite operation might be sensible.  It wasn't initially tagged [tag:c] so Mjölnir doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got it...

Here's what happens on my laptop (*Cygwin 2.831* (*pc032*) on *Win7* (*pc064*)):

```bash
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

When I pass ***-rdynamic***:

```bash
gcc -rdynamic
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Compared to ***-rdynamic1***:

```bash
gcc -rdynamic1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rdynamic1’
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

[[Man7]: GCC(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) mentions it (I'm not sure how relevant is that), but `gcc -v --help` doesn't display it under the linker specific options.
I thought that maybe something is different about how the *GCC*s are configured, but I didn't see any difference that would matter (both have ***--with-gnu-ld*** - which seems related - specified).

Then I downloaded *v4.8.2* and *v4.9.2* sources and start searching and comparing, but again I couldn't find anything (it's true, the search could be widely extended).

But while browsing the *configure* file, I noticed something that could be related, then I checked the *ld* command line options and I think I have an alternative:

Instead of ***-rdynamic***, you could pass ***-Wl,--export-all-symbols***. That works for me (that's not very relevant since *-rdynamic* also works for me, unlike in your case :) ).

Answer (score 3):

The link you give says:

> `-rdynamic`
>
> Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on *targets that support it*. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.

<sup>*(Emphasis added.)*</sup>

Is Cygwin using ELF format object files?  It seems unlikely.

Comment: Is there any way to remedy the issue or am I SOL?

Comment: Short answer: no idea.  You'd need to find out what the equivalent is for Windows systems, and I don't work on Windows enough to have that knowledge.  I'm not sure how it is going to relate to things like `dllimport` and `dllexport` which are a part of Windows DLL (shared library) handling.  As a short term measure, build without the `-rdynamic` option — does your code really need it?  Do you know where your code is using the facilities supported by `-rdynamic`?